# Change file modified date using date from file name

Tags: files, filenames, date

Change last modified date of multiple files as per date mentioned in the file's name

Files are

```
04-01-1981 XXXXXYYYYZZZZ.xml
19-11-1982 XXXXXYYYYZZZZ.xml
25-12-1981 XXXXXYYYYZZZZ.xml
```

The reason it is needed : I am doing migration of some articles, here each file is an article to be published. And already available custom import utility use file's last modified date as article published date. Hope this helps and clear the reason for it.

Comment: To the closers, and so that the OP can try and improve the question, what is unclear about  that question? Please avoid closing a question as unclear without first leaving a comment as to what is unclear.

Comment: To inforce on @StéphaneChazelas: We do not know _why_ the OP needs this, but at least archiving files is a typical use case of setting the mtime. `touch` is the command to go, which is widely misunderstood as being only useful to create an empty file.

Comment: The reason It is needed : I am doing migration of some articles, here each file is an article to be published. And already available custom import utility use file's last modified date as article published date. Hope this helps and clear the reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIXly:

```
for file in ??-??-????' '*.xml; do
  date=${file%% *}
  year=${date##*-}
  day=${date%%-*}
  month=${date%-*}
  month=${month#*-}
  touch -d "$year-$month-$day 00:00:00" -- "$file"
done
```

With `zsh`, you can shorten it to:

```
for f (??-??-????' '*.xml(N))
  touch -d "$f[7,10]-$f[4,5]-$f[1,2] 00:00:00" -- $f
```